# How can I see how much memory an application pool is using, in real-time?

Tags: memory, iis

I want to see how much memory an OData application pool is using, which is hosted in IIS. I can go to Worker Processes in IIS, but that doesn't update every 1 second/at some other timed interval.

Is there a way to see this application pool live memory usage in something other than IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with SysInternal Process Explorer, by showing the Command Line column.

[image]

Each application pool is hosted in a `w3w` worker process, and each application pool that's running will have its own thread.

Enable the Command Line column to see the complete path, which includes the name of the application pool e.g. `c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -ap "MyAppPool" -v "v4.0" -l "webengine4.dll" -a \\.\pipe\iisipmddd93617-e0d9-453b-b801-a06e516e0e79 -h "C:\inetpub\temp\apppools\MyAppPool\MyAppPool.config" -w "" -m 0 -t 20 -ta 0`

[image]

You can then open this thread, and review the Performance/Performance Graph tab(s) to see live resource usage.

Comment: I was about to suggest the exact same solution. cheers!